# how to get the normalize-space() xpath function to work?

Tags: c#, xpath

I am currently trying the following xpath

```
//tr[normalize-space(td/text())='User Name']
```

to get all the tr that contains a td that contain `'User Name'` or `'User    Name'` or `' User Name '` but its not working and I don't know what is wrong with the query :(
the data i want to find is in the following format

```
<tr><td>User Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>User     Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>  User Name   </td></tr>
```

So what is the right format to write this xpath query?

Edit:
it seem not work if the data is in the following format

```
<tr><td>x</td><td>User Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>x</td><td>y</td><td>User     Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>x</td><td>y</td><td>z</td><td>  User Name   </td></tr>
```

so now how can i write the xpath query?
note: "//tr[normalize-space(td/text()) = 'User Name']" wont work
but "//tr/td[normalize-space(text()) = 'User Name']" will work (but i want to get the tr and not the td element)

Comment: Please show a sample of your input data, starting with `<tr>`.

Comment: Everything looks fine at the first glance. I suspect the problem isn't with the query, but is with how you use the results. Can you show the query in context - if it's XSLT, the XSLT code that calls it and uses the results, if it's C# code directly, then that code.

Comment: well i am using the results using c# selectnodes(). but actually i am writing the statments in the debugger window. and i am getting 0 results. seems like a data problem.
will check it now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Now that you've edited the question, it makes sense. Let's consider this input:

```
<tr><td>x</td><td>User Name</td></tr>
```

and your non-working query:

```
//tr[normalize-space(td/text()) = 'User Name']
```

Now, `td/text()` means "select all child text nodes of all child `td` nodes of current node". In this case this will yield a node-set consisting two text nodes, `x` and `User Name`.

Now you call `normalize-space()` on that node-set. The type of the sole argument of `normalize-space()` is `string?`. Since a node-set is not a string, conversions kick in, per [section 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-Function-Calls) of XPath 1.0 recommendation:

> An argument is converted to type string as if by calling the string() function.

Now let's look at the [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-string) of string() in section 4.2:

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the **node in the node-set that is first in document order**. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

In our example, the first node "in document order" is the text node `x`, so it is the one which will be used; the second node is ignored. Thus, you end up calling `normalize-space('x')`. Naturally, this won't compare equal to 'User Name'. To make this work, use:

```
//tr[td[normalize-space(text()) = 'User Name']]
```

This can be transcribed as "select all `tr` nodes that have child `td` nodes, the first child `text()` node of which has a normalized string value of `User Name`" - which is what you want. Furthermore, you can simplify this to:

```
//tr[td[normalize-space() = 'User Name']]
```

Since a no-argument `normalize-space()` will apply to the current node (which will be `td`), and process all text nodes within.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine here:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"
    <table>
        <tr><td>User Name</td></tr>
        <tr><td> User   Name </td></tr>
        <tr><td>   User Name   </td></tr>
    </table>");

Console.WriteLine(
    xmlDoc.SelectNodes(
        "//tr[td[normalize-space(.) = 'User Name']]").Count); // shows "3"
```

Can you please update your question with a actual XML sample?

Comment: the actuall file is a big one so its not possbile to upload. but the sample is like the one u have but its not working for me

Comment: you dont need to upload entire file, just small piece where you're having problems

Comment: I updated my xpath and it works with your sample data; please take a look

Comment: sorry i accepted the answer of Pavel Minaev
but he has given some nice explanations.
but i appreciate your answer too and yours was faster :)