# Write XPath to test a specific navigation link in Rails with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, capybara

In my Rails 3.2.16 app with a Bootstrap 2.3 navigation list, I want to write a test that confirms that a specific item is active and that it has the right icon.  I'm using rspec 2.14.1 and capybara 2.1.0.

I assume the way to do this is with a capybara `has_xpath` test, but the classes that I need to check ("active" and "fa-folder-open") as well as the actual text ("Inbox") are at different levels of the HTML hierarchy.

Given this HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" role="navigation">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="/messages/my/inbox">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-fw">
      </i> Inbox</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="/messages/my/draft">
      <i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw">
      </i> Draft</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

is there an XPath that will confirm that the link with text "Inbox" is "active" and has the "fa-folder-open" icon?

**EDIT**

I copied the example HTML above the [XPath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/), where the Format button not only did some pretty formatting, it removed the closing `</i>` tags.  The raw HTML isn't as pretty:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" role="navigation">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="/messages/my/inbox">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-fw"></i> Inbox
</a>  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="/messages/my/draft">
      <i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Draft
</a>  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicolas' answer was helpful in suggesting that I use `contains`.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065069/550712) helped me see that I can nest the brackets to find nested nodes.

With some trial and error at [www.xpathtester.com](http://www.xpathtester.com), I came up with this XPath:

```
//li[contains(@class,'active') and a[text()=' Inbox' and i[contains(@class,'fa-folder-open')]]]
```

**EDIT**

My XPath above wasn't working on the raw HTML (see edited question).  The XPath wasn't finding the " Inbox" text, probably due to the line breaks before the `<\a>` tags.  With thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829427/550712)'s example of `normalize-space()` without the `text()` argument, this XPath works:

```
//li[contains(@class,'active') and a[normalize-space()='Inbox' and i[contains(@class,'fa-folder-open')]]]
```

Note that it must look for `'Inbox'`, not `' Inbox'`.  `normalize-space()` strips leading and trailing whitespace (including the line breaks that were causing problems), so the leading space must be removed from the text that it is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'active')//i[contains(text()='Inbox' and contains(@class, 'fa-folder-open')]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `contains`. Unfortunately this isn't working when I test it with XPath 2.0 at [www.xpathtester.com](http://www.xpathtester.com). Also note that the " Inbox" string is under the `<a>` node, not the `<i>` node. I'll post what I came up with.