# How to extract the text of the logged in user through Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

After logged in, there is a welcome "user name" message,

[image: Source code]

I want to write the xpath to capture that user. A few ideas I have tried:

```
//span[@id='WhoLoggedInUpdatePanel']//h1//br[contains(text(),'Welcome Sheikh')]

//h1[contains(text(),'"Welcome Sheikh"')]
```

None of those are working. Your suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Nothing in your example contains the text "Welcome Sheikh" - there are a LOT of space characters between the words !   Check out the normalize-space function - eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829176/how-to-get-the-normalize-space-xpath-function-to-work    (also, the <br> tag is not "correct" html, since it's an unclosed tag - should be "<br/>" - which also means it doesn't contain any text)

Comment: Do you want to *extract text* or *locate by text*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good to locate using the name because if login credential get changed then name will be change.

Use `//span[@id='WhoLoggedInUpdatePanel']/h1` and grab the text what present under `<h1>` or equivalent CSS selector `span[id='WhoLoggedInUpdatePanel']>h1`

```
String userName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='WhoLoggedInUpdatePanel']/h1")).getText();
```

and then verify whether your use is expected.

```
if(userName.contains("Sheikh")){
    System.out.println("valid user");
} else {
    System.out.println("invalid user");
}
```

Comment: Your CSS selector should be `#WhoLoggedInUpdatePanel > h1`. It's simpler, shorter and accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one to get text

```
String user = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='WhoLoggedInUpdatePanel']/h1").getAtrribute("innerText");
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text **Welcome Sheikh**, as it is a *text node* within its ancestor `<h1>` node, you need to use the method *executeScript()* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("///span[@id='WhoLoggedInUpdatePanel']/h1"));
String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
```